# Что делать, если русский язык поедает меня?

Tags: другое

Извините, что уже не первый раз пишу сюда с таким вопросом! Я уже не могу, честно. Я столько всего перепробовал для того, чтобы выучить русский язык, но ничего не получается. А очень хочется. Конечно, я не имею в виду знать прямо всё-всё. Я покупал различные книги, справочники и другие учебные пособия. Практически ничего не помогает. Голова побаливает, а я всё хочу да хочу. Причём не просто хочу, а пытаюсь и стараюсь, но ничего не получается. Мама как-то пытается меня подбодрить. Вокруг столько источников информации: сайты, книги и так далее. Всего так много, что я уже не знаю, что выбрать. Понимаете, проблема заключается в том, что я не могу анализировать написанное. А я хочу научиться. Мне не спится из-за моей проблемы. Я просто не могу спать и всё. Я недавно подумывал попробовать начать заниматься по школьным учебникам (с 1-11 класс). Пожалуйста, помогите мне. Мне вечно хочется перечитывать все прочитанное ранее. Я очень хочу выучить хотя бы базовый школьный курс, зная который я хотя бы мог бы спокойной писать. Пожалуйста, посоветуйте. У меня уже с психикой не в порядке что-то из-за этого становится. Очень прошу! Также я с родителями потратил большую сумму денег на приобретение книжек, а всё без толку...  Может, методика не та.. Я на грани срыва. Я даже звуки плохо классифицирую, не умею выделять корень, суффикс, приставку. По-видимому, это субъективное мнение. Однако может быть вполне реальной правдой...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поздравляю вас! Ваш уровень знаний довольно высокий, если судить по вашему развернутому письму. Вы даже знаете то, чего не знают многие корректоры: что в предложении *Я очень хочу выучить хотя бы базовый школьный курс, зная который я хотя бы мог бы спокойной писать* запятая после *который* не ставится.

Вас съедает не русский язык, а юношеский максимализм. Невозможно быть глубоким специалистом во всех узких сферах, коих в языкознании не счесть. И человек, защитивший кандидатскую диссертацию по одной теме, например по сравнительным оборотам, может быть абсолютным профаном в других и совершать множество пунктуационных ошибок.

Четко определитесь с целью. Если это грамотное письмо с перспективой работы в средствах массовой информации (корректором, литературным редактором или журналистом), вам нужны знания по орфографии и пунктуации + по стилистике русского языка. (И совсем не обязательно безошибочно выделять корень во всех словах.)

Всё это есть в настольной книге издательских работников: Розенталь Д. Э. Справочник по правописанию и литературной правке. – М.: Айрис-пресс, 2012. Скачать можно здесь: http://eknigi.org/gumanitarnye_nauki/180694-spravochnik-po-pravopisaniyu-i-literaturnoy-pravke.html

Если вам непонятны какие-то термины, их можно найти в Интернете. Решайте конкретные, практические задачи, а не глобально-теоретические. Например, возьмите безграмотный текст с какого-нибудь форума и исправьте его. Даже если вы не сделаете это идеально, у вас появятся вопросы к тексту, ответы на которые можно найти у Розенталя и на сайте Gramota.ru. Вопросы и ответы записывайте в отдельный файл - ведите архив актуальной для вас информации, пополняйте и расширяйте его.

И помните, что формирование грамотности - процесс бесконечный и необозримый. Нельзя задаться целью освоить всё, например, за год и достичь её. Это скорее образ жизни - внимательное отношение к словам и знакам препинания, вопрошание и поиск конкретной информации. И этот процесс должен быть увлекательным и приятным, а не выматывающим и убийственным для психики.

И вот вам в будущую копилку: *Практически **ничего** не помогает.* Правильно: Практически **ничто** не помогает. Задаем вопрос: не помогает что? Ничто.

Будут вопросы - обращайтесь.

Comment: Вы примерно описали мою цель. Однако как я буду читать этот учебник и получать от него полезную информацию, если я не понимаю основы?

Answer (score 6):

Может, стоит обратиться к преподавателю? Может, к школьному, может, к репетитору. Ведь наши учебники - это не самоучители. Вот если бы к каждому заданию был ответ с подробным разбором. Но такие книги крайне редки.  Решебники не в счет, там есть ответы (не всегда, впрочем, верные), а объяснений нет или почти нет. Более того, ошибки бывают и в учебниках, оценить, ошибка ли это, а может, альтернативная точка зрения, может только грамотный преподаватель.

Comment: Я ходил к одному преподавателю-женщине, которая мне дала две книги. Одна с упражнениями, друга написана Розенталем (и ещё кем-то). Если я не знаю базовые знания, то я вообще ничего не смогу...

Comment: Ищите преподавателя, который не просто даст вам книги или перескажет написанное в них, а позанимается с Вами, учитывая именно Ваши пробелы, ваш тип восприятия и нервной системы, подберет нужные именно Вам упражнения. Кто-то из форумчан Вам уже говорил, что можно знать все правила, а писать  с массой ошибок. А можно и не знать всех правил, а писать грамотно.

Comment: Преподавателей, к сожалению, нет. Единственный человек, с которым я могу заниматься, - это мама. :)

Comment: Вы в каком городе живете? В любом случае, есть школьные преподаватели. Есть репетиторы. Есть онлайн-репетиторы. Есть видеоуроки на образовательных сайтах. Надо успокоиться, отдохнуть и начинать сначала. Определить цель - зачем мне это нужно? Просто хорошо писать диктанты? Сдать ГИА? ЕГЭ? Писать лучше, чем я писал до сих пор? Отвечать лучше других в классе? Поступить на филологический факультет? Потом,исходя из целей, уже искать пути достижения.

Comment: Живу я в России, в совсем не большом городе. Вообще, я хотел бы просто считать себя грамотным человеком. Потом, возможно, связать с этим свою деятельность и профессию.

Comment: Поверьте, в маленьких городках есть очень грамотные преподаватели, не хуже столичных.

Comment: Ещё деньги ведь нужны.

Answer (score 3):

Это не русский язык поедает Вас, это Вы себя поедаете, занимаетесь самоедством (смысл фразеологизма понятен? Значит. всё в порядке у Вас с русским языком). "Всё и сразу" - это возрастное.Так не бывает.Как для того чтобы узнать человека. нужно съесть пуд соли (то есть провести в общении много времени),так и узнать язык можно, общаясь с ним постоянно "на короткой ноге" и познавая его нюансы. База у Вас неплохая, для 8 класса очень даже неплохо.Дальше пойдёт "мерцающее повторение" - изучение сложного предложения с повтором и отработкой трудных тем орфографии или пропущенных по разным причинам тем. Терпение и ещё раз терпение - у Вас всё получится. Если хотите, давайте позанимаемся по Скайпу - пишите на эл.почту -l_shepeleva@mail.ru

Answer (score 1):

Вы, главное, так не переживайте! Хотя приятно слышать, что кто-то сейчас еще волнуется из-за русского языка и мечтает его выучить на должном уровне.
В моей жизни всегда количество переходило в качество. Может, и Вам поможет просто больше писать. Попробуйте писать рассказы. По ходу будут возникать сложные случаи с правописанием, так Вы выносите их сюда. Постепенно запомните, и грамотность станет уже интуитивной.

Comment: Вы совсем не понимаете. Чтобы писать, нужно хоть что-то понимать. Я ничего не знаю. Это не совсем моя цель (писать рассказы).

Comment: Вы себя недооцениваете. Это неправда, что Вы ничего не знаете. Вы задаете вопросы и даже отвечаете на вопросы других. Преподаватель и должен помочь Вам поверить в свои силы.

Comment: Я-то отвечаю, да. Но это пустяковые вопросы, на мой взгляд.

Answer (score 1):

Удивительно, Tagirix, но для восьмого класса пишите вы очень хорошо. А потом жалуетесь, что ничего не знаете. То что вы знаете сейчас, нас в школе, поверьте , не учили. Все знания я приобрел в институте, и знаете, я до сих пор продолжаю самосовершенствоваться. Единственный способ успокоиться - нанять репетитора. Ну, или, консультируйтесь с вашими школьными педагогами, обращайтесь сюда, в концов концов. Вам всегда помогут! Удачи!